# Insert li before last two elements inside ul using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following ul list and I try to insert an element before the last two elements.

That will be dynamically and always add them before the last two ones.

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li id="first">first</li>
   <li id="second">second</li>       

   <li id="beforeLast">before last</li>
   <li id="last">last</li>
</ul>
```

how can I insert a new `li` before li `beforeLast`

P.S.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$('<li>test</li>').prependTo($('#myList li:last-child').prev('li'));
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+insertbefore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `:nth-last-child()` for this :

```
$('#myList').find(' > li:nth-last-child(2)').before('<li>New</li>');
```

This way the "before last" element will be selected. with `.before()` a new element before the selected element will be added.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrff5/)**

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) like:

```
$("<li id='newList'>New Li</li>").insertBefore("#beforeLast");
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4DBtX/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `("<li></li>").insertBefore($("#beforelast"))` feature from jQuery